# How to wait for a function to end on iOS/Swift, before starting the second one

Tags: ios, swift

I basically have to methods, which are being called in my viewDidLoad. The first one gets the user's search preferences and saves the preferences to variables at the top. After that I want to access and work with these variables in the second function. But now the variables are always nil when I want to access them in the second function.

How do I need to adjust my viewDidLoad, so the second function is only executed once and my data request has been performed successfully?

```
var searchLocation = String()
var searchLocationCoordinates = [String:Double]()
var searchRange = Int()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Gets the user's search preference
    getTheSearchLocationAndRange()

    // Loads the data from the database
    loadDataFromDatabase()
}
```

I have read stuff so far with dispatch_asynch or completion handler. Maybe someone can post some code which I can use in my viewDidLoad and makes it work?

Comment: You don't say so, but getThSearchLocationAndRange must be asynchronous? In which case you should not wait, that would make your GUI hang. Instead you could make the first function take a completion block as a parameter and put the second function as the block body is one way to do it, there are others.

Comment: Okay yeah got it! Do you have some sample code which shows it to me? But that was also one idea which I saw in other posts with the completion handler!

Comment: Is there a dispatch function in getTheSearchLocationAndRange?

Comment: Hi FredericP No there isn't one yet.

Comment: @Mattk90 Did you try the code I posted in my answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I've found an solution. I basically called the function at the end of the first one.

So basically:

```
    var searchLocation = String()
    var searchLocationCoordinates = [String:Double]()
    var searchRange = Int()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Gets the user's search preference
        getTheSearchLocationAndRange()
    }

    func getTheSearchLocationAndRange() {
    // Code for getTheSearchLocationAndRange()

    loadDataFromDatabase()
    }

    func loadDataFromDatabase(){
    // Code for loadDataFromDatabase()
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this is it makes the `getTheSearchLocationAndRange()` function less useful, unless it's *always* supposed to call `loadDataFromDatabase`.  If you want the method to be more flexible, use the completion block method.

Comment: Okay I agree on that point. In my case I would never need both functions independently. Therefore I guess I can solve it like this. But I give you credit, that you solution might be the programmatically better one! hahha

Comment: This one could have been failed if one of the process takes longer time in **getTheSearchLocationAndRange()** This is not a solution at all.

Comment: This isn't a solution to anything other than your particular situation. It might be working for you, but for the wrong reason. If you have asynchronous functionality within the parent function, the child function will still get called in line without waiting for the other code to complete.

Answer (score 22):

You can use Swift closures! They are made for that.

Please refer to the Apple guide: *[Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)*

Here's the code you need in your particular case.

FinishedDownload is the closure. When `getTheSearchLocationAndRange()` is called, its code is executed until the `completed()` line which waits for all processes of the function to finish. Once the processes finish (downloads for example), `completed()` calls the closure which activates the code defined in `getTheSearchLocationAndRange { () -> () in`. Therefore, `loadDataFromDatabase()` is only called once `getTheSearchLocationAndRange()` has entirely finished executing and the data is present (not nil).

```
    var searchLocation = String()
    var searchLocationCoordinates = [String:Double]()
    var searchRange = Int()
    typealias FinishedDownload = () -> ()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getTheSearchLocationAndRange()
    }

    func getTheSearchLocationAndRange(completed: FinishedDownload) {

           // Code for searching Location Range HERE

           completed()
    }

    getTheSearchLocationAndRange { () -> () in
        loadDataFromDatabase()
    }
```

I hope this solved your issue and answered your question :)

BTW, about the "leaving your GUI hanging" part, Alamofire takes automatically care of this for you. If you don't use Alamofire, then you will have to manually assign the asynchronous request to a background thread so your GUI doesn't become unresponsive.

Comment: What if I have parameters in the getTheSearchLocationAndRange that I need returned

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a demo project and posted it on GitHub that simulates handling an asynchronous network download. Take a look at [DuncanMC/SwiftCompletionHandlers](https://github.com/DuncanMC/SwiftCompletionHandlers).

Specifically look at the method asyncFetchImage(), which does almost exactly what this thread is talking about: Uses an asynchronous method internally, and takes a completion block that it calls once the asynchronous load is done.

That is the general pattern you should use. Write a method that takes a completion block/closure. Internally, have that method call whatever asynchronous function it needs and then call your completion closure from inside the asynchronous method call's completion closure.

The function `asyncFetchImage` looks like this:

```
func asyncFetchImage(imageName imageName: String,
  completion: (
    image: UIImage?,
    status: String) -> ())
{
  print("Entering \(#function)")

  //Simulate a network operation by waiting a few seconds before loading an image
  let nSecDispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(3.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
  let queue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
  dispatch_after(nSecDispatchTime, queue)
    {
      () -> Void in
      let result = UIImage(named: imageName)
      print("Loading image in background")
      let status = result != nil ? "image loaded" : "Error loading image"
      print("About to call completion handler")
      completion(image: result, status: status)
  }
  print("Leaving \(#function)")
}
```