# Can't display data asynchronous swift2, tableView is refreshing before the data is retrieved

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I'm trying to load a tableview with custom tableview cells.

this is how the `viewDidLoad()` of my tableview controller look:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView?.delegate = self;
        self.tableView?.dataSource = self;

        //Clean array data
        TableData.removeAll()

        //Retrieve data asynchronously
        let call = webApi()
        call.retrieveAllShops()

        doTableRefresh()

    }
```

TableData is a global array where I put all the json Data.
So I clean it before fill it again.
I fill it in `call.retrieveAllShops()`

```
private func retrieveAllShops(){
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: userApiCallUrl)!)

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        request.HTTPBody = postParam.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }
            if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }


            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            let json: AnyObject? = responseString!.parseJSONString

            self.parseJson((json as! NSMutableArray))

        }

        task.resume()
    }
```

Finally in `parseJson()` I fill the global array TableData:

```
private func parseJson(json : NSMutableArray){

for j in json {
//Create main value
            guard let value = j.valueForKey("value")?.valueForKey("value")! else{
                continue
            }

//Get name
            guard let Name : String = (value.valueForKey("Name")?.valueForKey("en") as? String) else {
                continue
            }
TableData.append(Name)
}
}
```

Then back in the tableView Controller, I call `doTableRefresh()`

```
private func doTableRefresh(){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            return
        })
    }
```

And finally I have those two methods.

```
    func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
    {
        if(searchActive) {
            return filtered.count
        }
        return TableData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell : shopsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("shopCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! shopsTableViewCell
        if(searchActive){
            cell.textLabel?.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.textLabel?.text = TableData[indexPath.row]
        }

cell.shopTitle = TableData[indexPath.row]
return cell
}
```

Now If I set a breakpoint in the `return TableData.count` line of the method `tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)` it always enters here at the first place, before the async call has loaded the global array, thus it returns 0 and my tableview cells doesn't display at all.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Edit:

After had made some changes in my `viewDidLoad` method:

```
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView?.delegate = self;
        self.tableView?.dataSource = self;

        //Clean array data
        TableData.removeAll()

        //Retrieve data asynchronously
        let call = webApi()
        call.retrieveAllShops({
            data in
            self.doTableRefresh()
        })

}
```

And in my `retrieveAllShops()` method:

func retrieveAllShops(success: SuccessClosure){
    setGetShopsListUrl()

```
call()

success(data: "sucess")
```

}

My app is crashing here:

[image]

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)
```

Could look as the outlet is not connected so, I deleted the old connection and did a new one, but the same result (old connection was ok):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call doTableRefresh after json parsing

```
    let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let json: AnyObject? = responseString!.parseJSONString

    self.parseJson((json as! NSMutableArray))

    self.doTableRefresh()
    ...
```

Edited

// create it globally

```
public typealias SuccessClosure = (data: String?) -> (Void)
```

and in your class where you are calling call.retrieveAllShops() 
pass SuccessClosure as a parameter

```
 call.retrieveAllShops({
  data in 
 self.doTableRefresh()
 //  refresh tableview here

})
```

and in retrieveAllShops method

```
private func retrieveAllShops(success: SuccessClosure) {

...
 self.parseJson((json as! NSMutableArray))
success("sucess") // you can pass data according to your requirment here

}
```

Comment: the problem is I need to pass the tableView outlet as a param to that call. And My json is loading in another swift file. May I pass the tableView as a param or is not a good coding practise?

Comment: all right. and you shouldn't . simply create a closure and call it when your parsing done.

Comment: what is a closure?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html or http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/ read from here

Comment: you can do in this way. but you must learn how closures works.

Comment: I'm reading tutorials but is not very clear. An example would be very appreciated

Comment: it's because your tableview property not connected to IBOutlet. create a IBOutlet property of tableview.

Comment: It is conected. Look at the updated post, I've added images of the connection. If I add an interrogation to the line were it crashes, it doesn't crash anymore but it doesn't load any cell too, so the same situation as I were at the beginning...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114221/discussion-between-sahil-beri-and-user3033437).

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong. That is the nature of async networking.

The only think you're missing is that at the end of the completion block in your `retrieveAllStops()` method you need to add a call to  `doTableRefresh()` (just under the call to `self.parseJason()`.

It doesn't do any good to call `doTableRefresh()` in viewDidLoad, so you might as well remove that call. (The table view array data won't be available yet.)

### Edit:

If the table view is defined in another class then add a method dataIsAvailable and call that. (Or as @SahilBeri says, add a closure to the `retrieveAllStops()` method and invoke the closure once the data has been downloaded and parsed.)

If you decide to call a dataIsAvailable method, then you might want to add a delegate to your JSON fetching class and have the `dataIsAvailable()` method be a delegate method.

Comment: I can't call doTableRefresh() from my json parsing function because I need the tableView outlet for this and it's not in the json parsing file..

Comment: thanks, can you explain a bit how works the dataIsAvailable() method? were shall I declare it, in my view controller? how to call this method? do I have to instantiate my current tableView Controller from Json parse function and from there call the method?? How can I acces to this current instance of tableView controller from Json parse function?

Comment: You either want to use the delegation design pattern or user a completion handler. Here is a thread that includes a sample project showing how to write a Swift function that takes a completion handler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829749/how-to-wait-for-a-function-to-end-on-ios-swift-before-starting-the-second-one/36830220#36830220