# Geocoding function returns void, need it to return CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: ios, mapkit, yelp

I'm using MapKit's forward geocoding function and created a function that will take an address from the Yelp API and, well, forward geocode it. However, this function inherently returns void and won't function properly otherwise if I change Void to CLLocationCoordinate2D. All I need is for it to return "coordinate."

```
func forwardGeocoding(address: String)  {

let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
    if((error) != nil){
        print("Error", error)
    }
    if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
        let coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate
    }
})

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Geocoding is asynchronous. This means you make a function call, which immediately returns before the results are available. Thus, you CAN'T return the coordinate as the result of your function.

Instead, you need to write your function to take a completion block and write that completion block to take the coordinate as a parameter. Then you invoke forwardGeocoding function and pass in the code that you want to be executed once the geocoding is complete.

Check out my answer on this thread: [How to wait for a function to end on iOS/Swift, before starting the second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829749/how-to-wait-for-a-function-to-end-on-ios-swift-before-starting-the-second-one/36830220#36830220)

For a sample project that handles the exact situation you're dealing with.